# APK COENCTADO A AZURE SQL SERVER

Tags: azure, apk

Estoy desarrolando una aplicacion movil, en UNITY la cual me genera un APK, PERO NO logro conectarla a la base de datos adquiri AZURE SQL SERVER, y tengo la cadena de conexion pero cuando pongo el string en mi clase conexion de c# en unity, y genero el apk no me conecta en un dispositivo movil, me pueden ayudar por favor...... perdon me olvide de mencionar que a nivel de aplicacion interna en mi computador si funciona si se conecta solo tengo el problema en el movil.
Ayuda.

Comment: 4 Cosas: 1. Bienvenido a SOes. 2. Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 3. Revisa el tour: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour así verás cómo es el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso obtienes tu primera medalla. 4. La conexión a base de datos para aplicaciones móviles va desde un endpoint de una web API, no directamente desde el APK aunque de poder se puede, solo que se incrementa un riesgo enorme de seguridad porque tendrías que habilitar conexiones desde cualquier IP. En otras palabras, te quedaría así: APK -> Web API -> SQL Azure. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero por la premura del tiempo a entregar el proyecto para solo un testeo por parte del cliente me podrias indicar como lo hago sin necesidad de recurrir a las api

Comment: Claro, aquí tienes: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-configure?view=azuresql

Comment: Que tal, sabes que esa configuracion me sirvio a nivel de servidor y base de datos cuando ingreso la ip de donde estoy tratando de ingresar al azure sql, pero todavia no puedo acceder a mi backend(tablas, vistas, store procedures) desde mi aplicativo movil, no se que mas hacer, incluso le agregue la ip movil de mi operadora telefonica aun asi no me deja utilizar mi aplicactivo a nivel de aplicacion en mi movil que es un apk, pero en modo desarrollo si puedo acceder.... yo se que mas puedo hacer.